# phpMyAdmin showing negative total records for a database table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I check my database, it's showing negative records for a table (e.g. -200,000), other tables' records are static.

When I view the table and go back to the summary, it changes randomly to -198,000, or -220,000... It's just not static.

What could be happening?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is an old question but one that I ran into and this post was the first thing to show up on google so I thought I would put the right answer up.

You'll notice that all of the "negative mysql records" questions are with large tables or databases. This isn't a negative sign its ~, which means approximately. It's basically saying that there's around that many records. As far as I can tell, it shows up once any table gets more than 20,000 records in it in phpMyAdmin. This is also why the askers numbers keep fluctuating, it's not exact.

Comment: I need to up my glasses power! Thanks!

Comment: haha ;D i thought it was cause im importing a laaaarge sql file at the moment but nope, trolled by a tilde..

Comment: I need glasses too ;)

Comment: Hi, when I enter the table and there is a total at the top (but no ~ sign), the value does not match the value when I run the SQL Count Query

Answer (score 4):

as Eric Strom already mention that, it is correct which is that sign mean estimated total row by phpMyAdmin. you can always get a rid of that ~ sign or get exact value of its total row by clicking this number. here it is on my 
 own table example :

[image]

and after click that number that started with ~ sign, you will get total row exactly after being re-calculated.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

go to phpmyadmin

1. select the problematic table
2. choose "operations" from the tabs on the top
3. look under the "table maintainance" block what options you have. I would simply click them all by order, let each operation finish, and see if problem remains. 
   Each operation has a help button next to it to explain what it does. (My bet is that FLUSH should fix your problem).

Answer (score 0):

If FLUSH didn't solve your problem, try to de-fragment your table, This variations in numbers of table-rows usually occurs when table contains billions of rows.

There will be always some limitations in PHP-Myadmin.

And same time you can also fire a query "`select count(id) from tableName`" to get the exact number of rows.