# What would be a fix or migration for phpMyAdmin's 20,000 row limitation and is anything really unstable?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am working with large amounts of data and starting to get odd behavior when checking my data in phpMyAdmin. Row counts display `~` prefixes when count is high, supposedly estimates of the count. I will also get for example; 711 pages of data (x 30 rows), select the 711th page (last one) and then it will offer up more pages in the 800's, that are equal to none when selected.

This post describes the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205062/phpmyadmin-showing-negative-total-records-for-a-database-table) but it does not offer a solution or potential instabilities. I have taken on perfecting my data types, keys and insertion process with little luck on understanding how to fix this or if there is any unseen deprecation of my data. The inserts and updates come from local PHP and off-server Python if that makes any difference.

Comment: perhaps you shouldn't be using phpmyadmin for his

Comment: @Dagon maybe your right, I have a few options in mind but I wanted to better understand this issue a bit more. If the issues are strictly phpMyAdmin and an issue that is irreparable, I will be able to sell the seniors on getting new software.

Comment: According to the main page "phpMyAdmin is a free software **tool** written in PHP, intended **to handle the administration** of MySQL over the Web." It is _a_ tool. Not _the_ tool. You could stick with it but switch, say to plain SQL using the standard command line `mysql` tool for the "big requests" once in a while.

Comment: As an alternative, since pyhMyAdmin is an opensource software, you could [contribute](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/improve.php) to the project and fix the issue.

Comment: I'm going to side with Dagon for this one.  The code you would need to write to display that data would be only a couple of hours' work for you, I'm sure.  You could also add in some automated data checking, which is what computers are for, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using InnoDB tables, approximate counts are one of its "things", as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html). It has nothing really to do with phpMyAdmin. phpMyAdmin is just a frontend for the database and it relies on the data given by the database; if the database can only supply approximate counts quickly, then that's it.

And since phpMyAdmin is only a tool to simplify basic interactions with the database, I don't see the big issue. It shouldn't be your primary tool to browse through 800 pages of data to begin with. But, if you'd follow the hints provided by phpMyAdmin, you'd end up with a solution [here](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/FAQ_3.11).

Comment: InnoDB really gave me what to look at and solved the issues, thank you.