# After PDO rollback, phpMyAdmin won't show the correct row count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

[image: Showing 1 record]

[image: SELECT returns zero rows]

I'm using PDO's `rollBack()` function after an `INSERT` statement. It works correctly, however after I truncate my table and make sure that the row count is being showed as `~0` in phpMyAdmin's panel, executing query and then rolling back causes row count being showed as `~1` (or how many rows I inserted and then rolled back).

When I select all the rows, there isn't any, but phpMyAdmin still shows not zero. I don't know if it's relevant to the application or to my code. Here's the code:

```
// begin the transaction
$this->db->beginTransaction();
// create sql query
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`name`) VALUES (?) ";
// prepare connection with the statement
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
// bind parameters to query
$stmt->bindParam(1, $this->name);
// execute the statement
$stmt->execute();
// just for testing
$this->db->rollBack();
```

- My table is `InnoDB`.
- I have selected all the rows with MySQL Workbench and still no rows.
- There are rows if I don't roll back so I'm pretty sure that the query is working.
- If I rollback a record and then insert new one without rolling back, selecting all returns 1 row but the shown count in the phpMyAdmin panel is still `~2`.
- phpMyAdmin version is 4.1.13
- PHP version is 5.4.24
- MySQL Server version is 5.6.19

Is this a bug or expected behaviour? If I keep rolling back some records, will it cause any trouble in the future such as returning incorrect row counts?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311965/what-would-be-a-fix-or-migration-for-phpmyadmins-20-000-row-limitation-and-is-a/17314997#17314997

Comment: @deceze My bad is that I said my table is MyISAM but it isn't, it is InnoDB (Edited the question). So what I understand from your answer is that "it happens with InnoDB"?

Comment: Yep, pretty much. That's why it's "~1", not "1".