# MySQL row number is -58684. How can it be possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, phpmyadmin, innodb

I have a .csv file contains writer names in this order:

```
Writer A
Writer B
Writer C
```

Here is my .csv file contents, if you want to look. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Byzvzp
Here is the full .csv file that contains 58463 rows : http://tny.cz/357e984f

I want to import these names into my writer_name column in my writer table.
I import my csv file via import section in phpmyadmin. I click import, select my csv file, select format as "CSV Using Load Data", fill column name as writer_name and upload the data into table successfully.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpEt3Q7Z' INTO TABLE `writer` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'# 58463 rows affected.
```

After the process, number of rows changes whenever I refresh my database tables. Also it shows there are -58684 rows in my table, which is impossible. I am probably doing something wrong here, but unable to understand what it is.

My table type is innoDB.

Comment: Probably you have a header in the csv which is also getting added ?

Comment: I created a file called load.csv via my IDE (PhpStorm) and pasted the writer names in it, it's like a plain text file. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: well a blank line might have some effect too. Hard to say whats went wrong.

Comment: If any of the rows have imbedded semi-colons or line feed, it could cause that row to split into two rows in your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's not a minus(negative) symbol, it's a FRIKKIN' **TILDE**! When I run this query, I get exact number of rows in my table, the result is the same.

`select count(writer_id) from writer`

There is a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205062/phpmyadmin-showing-negative-total-records-for-a-database-table).

Problem, it turns out isn't a problem, has been solved.